# Having a fcaption align with the img

Tags: css, html, semantics

This is my code

```
<figure>
 <img class="music-player--album-image" src="img/album1.png">
 <figcaption>Fig1. - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

And this produces the image and below it the figcaption, what I'm trying to do is have the caption to the side of the image, aligned vertically as well to be in the center next to the image.

Any ideas how?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY THIS - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LL9ardqa/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<figure>
 <img class="music-player--album-image" src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
 <figcaption>Fig1. - A view of the pulpit rock in Norway.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Give CSS style `display: table;` to `figure`, `display: table-cell;` and `vertical-align: middle;` to `img, figcaption`. You can also use padding to style the `figcaption`.

**CSS**

```
figure {
    display: table;
}
img, figcaption {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
figcaption {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```